# Deserialization XML raw in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, shred

I have a table in SQL Server. In this table, I have a column `Response` of datatype `XML` value. How can I deserialize this XML value like a new table?

My table columns are: `CreateDate`, `Request` and `Response`.

```
<request-message version="1.0">
<request class="GET_ALL">
    <parameter name="IsInSystem" type="System.Boolean">True</parameter>
    <parameter name="ConfirmDate" type="System.DateTime">2021-05-04 00:00:00.000</parameter>
    <parameter name="ConfirmTime" type="System.DateTime">2021-05-04 00:00:00.000</parameter>
</request>
```

I want to write this response to a table with parameters as a column.

Comment: This is not a code writing service.  Show what you've tried and an example of what you need and we can help you fix it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do - plus the XML shown is invalid (missing end tag for `<request-message>`).

Maybe something like this?? I'm just iterating over the `<parameter>` nodes and outputting all relevant info I can think of, as a relational data set:

```
DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, Request XML)

INSERT INTO @SomeTable (ID, Request)
VALUES (1, '<request-message version="1.0">
<request class="GET_ALL">
    <parameter name="IsInSystem" type="System.Boolean">True</parameter>
    <parameter name="ConfirmDate" type="System.DateTime">2021-05-04 00:00:00.000</parameter>
    <parameter name="ConfirmTime" type="System.DateTime">2021-05-04 00:00:00.000</parameter>
</request></request-message>'    )


SELECT
    ID,
    RequestClass = xc.value('(../@class)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
    ParamName = XC.value('(./@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ParamType = XC.value('(./@type)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ParamValue = XC.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(250)')
FROM
    @SomeTable
CROSS APPLY
    Request.nodes('/request-message/request/parameter') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

This would give you a result something like this:

| ID | RequestClass | ParamName | ParamType | ParamValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GET_ALL | IsInSystem | System.Boolean | True |
| 1 | GET_ALL | ConfirmDate | System.DateTime | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | GET_ALL | ConfirmTime | System.DateTime | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: Actually, you're righ @marc_s  . I need this. But I can not convert XML value to text. I get the xml value from table.

Comment: @mordeby: not sure what you mean - this ***IS*** from a `XML` datatype  column - it's not "text" .....